# How do I generate random numbers in Haskell, using random-fu, with platform-agnostic code?

Tags: haskell, random, numbers, multiplatform

I can't figure out how to use `Data.Random.Source.IO` to generate random numbers in a multiplatform way.

I can generate random numbers in Unix using `Data.Random.Source.DevRandom`, and there is an example in the GitHub documentation for Windows using `Data.Random.Source.MWC`, but there is no example code for using `Data.Random.Source.IO`.

Comment: All that module does is define a `MonadRandom` instance for `IO`, using `DevRandom` or `MWC`. So you use it like any other instance.

Comment: Could you give a working snippet that uses `MonadRandom`? I tried find/replacing `DevRandom` with `MonadRandom` in my code, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I have converted the github example to use `Source.IO`

```
import Data.Random
import Data.Random.Source.IO


logNormal :: Double -> Double -> RVar Double
logNormal mu sigmaSq = do
    x <- normal mu sigmaSq
    return (exp x)

main = sample (logNormal 5 1) >>= print
```

You can see in the [source](https://github.com/mokus0/random-fu/blob/master/random-source/src/Data/Random/Source/IO.hs) of `Data.Random.Source.IO` that it just defines the suitable instance for `MonadRandom IO`.

You can generate a uniform random number from a list as

```
import Data.Random
import Data.Random.Source.IO

main = sample (randomElement [0..9]) >>= print
```

Comment: I *almost* get it. Could you modify your example to generate a uniform random number between `[0 .. 9]`?

Comment: @mcandre See the example I added.

Comment: Is there any way to easily extend this to get a list of n lognormal random variates? Or perhaps a lazy list of random variates?